# How can I add synonyms with elasticSearch on coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, coffeescript

I'm coding with coffeescript and my code contains some elasticSearch queries, now I want to add synonyms but as a beginner I don't know where I can add the filter and what I should do before write the filter to define synonyme and what's the correct synatx to do that !?

This is my code without synonyms :

```
  processArrFn['firstpart'] = (nomCallback) =>

    client.search
      index: 'project'
      type: 'first_doc'
      size: @_SEARCH_SIZE
      body: 
        query:
          function_score:
            query:
              query_string:
                fields: ["NOM_OBJ^5","DEFINITION^3","TYPE^1"]
                query: queryTxt
            boost_mode: "multiply"
    .then (res) => nomCallback(null, res)
```

Comment: Do you know how to do it in JS and are just having trouble with the CS syntax, or are you asking how to add synonyms at all?

Comment: No I'm not sure about the js code ! what I found in elasticsearch documentation was logic for me but I'm not sure where I should put it exactly ! so I'm asking how to do it at all @Mathletics